# Angular: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstCreatePass' of null

Tags: angular, angular-components

After updating angular to version 10, I see this console error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstCreatePass' of null

It was not there before the update.
It is shown when loading a view with a custom component.

What may be missing?

Comment: I am also getting the same error, for a child component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out it was because I also updated the ngx-custom-validators package too.

But the wanted version of ngx-custom-validators is 8.0.0.
After changing the version it worked.

https://github.com/rsaenen/ngx-custom-validators/issues/39#issuecomment-654024141

Comment: It's working. but equalTo and notEqualTo validators making an error when ng build --prod.

Type 'NgModel' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': setValue, patchValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange, and 28 more.

any idea about this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have recieved same error message because I had one library symlinked and I didn't turn on **"preserveSymlinks"** option in **angular.json**. Found answer here [How to use angular library locally with hot reload? [Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847493/how-to-use-angular-library-locally-with-hot-reload-error-cannot-read-properti)

You have to put variable `"preserveSymlinks": true` in `angular.json` into build options of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when upgrading to angular 11. We are loading the modules dynamically and using custom elements (more details here: https://angular.io/guide/elements).

In my case, instead of overriding the files on the server I just had to first delete all the old files and then upload the updated files, this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened because I was using slightly incompatible libraries in my two package.jsons.

I was using the ckeditor library, but one of my projects was using the NPM package "**ng2-ckeditor**", and one was using the NPM package "**ckeditor4-angular**". They were close enough that Angular didn't give the error **ckeditor is not a known element** because they both had a component with that name... but they had very different internal structure.

The error went away when I made sure both **package.json**s were using the same NPM package.

Answer (score 0):

I received the error when I tried to use components from an Angular library inside an Angular application. It turns out that I used different versions for `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` in my library and application.

I had to update my application so that version of those packages matched exactly (even the patch version)

**Before**

Versions in my library:

- `@angular/cdk` : 15.0.4
- `@angular/material` : 15.0.4

Versions in my application

- `@angular/cdk` : 15.0.0
- `@angular/material` : 15.0.0

**After**

Versions in my library:

- `@angular/cdk` : 15.0.4
- `@angular/material` : 15.0.4

Versions in my application

- `@angular/cdk` : 15.0.**4**
- `@angular/material` : 15.0.**4**