# Upgrade from Angular 12.0.4 to Angular 12.1.0 produces runtime error, reverting to 12.0.4 compile error

Tags: angular, typescript

There's a somewhat related issue posted here: [Angular: TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstCreatePass' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656063/angular-typeerror-cannot-read-property-firstcreatepass-of-null)

...but that's with different Angular versions involved, and the solution there doesn't help me. The runtime error which is in common is:

> Cannot read property 'firstCreatePass' of null

Another possible difference is that I'm attempting to create an Angular library. You're supposed to disable Ivy for building libraries, so I wondered if that might be part of the problem, but the error happens with Ivy either enabled or disabled.

If I revert to 12.0.4, I can't compile... on one of two macOS systems. 12.0.4 works fine on my laptop, not on my desktop. The compile error is:

> Error: Symbol CommonModule declared in /Users/kshetline/programming_projects/npm-packages/tubular_ng-widgets/node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts is not exported from @angular/common

I've synced the versions of @angular/cli and npm and node between the two computers, so I have no idea why one can compile with 12.0.4, and the other can't. I've completely thrown away node_modules and package-lock.json many times.

I don't know if there's any single particularly relevant part of my code I could post here to help, but the full project can be found here: https://github.com/kshetline/tubular_ng-widgets

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem - "preserveSymlinks" set to "true" in the angular.json build section fix the problem for me.

I am using npm link in order to test/develop additional package in a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to have been a corrupted node and/or npm environment.

As an experiment, I copied the complete project, using Angular 12.0.4, from where it worked on my laptop to where it wasn't working on my desktop, including the very-large-and-slow-to-copy node_modules folder, rather than allowing node_modules to be rebuilt by my desktop system.

The project ran just fine.

So I set aside the working node_modules directory, and the corresponding package-lock.json.

I completely purged node, npm, and nvm from my destop, all code and caches. I then reinstalled NodeJS 14.17.1 and updated npm after that.

With the new node/npm enviroment, the project rebuild and ran locally without a hitch. After that, I was also able to update to Angular 12.1.0 without any problems either.

I wouldn't have imagined node and/or npm could screw up so much, in such a confusing way!

Comment: I confirm, with npm 7.x the upgrade to Angular 12.1.0 is failing, downgrading npm to previous 6.14.x, shipped with NodeJS 14.7.1, the upgrade completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same compile error too, I'm using npm link and my issue was missing:

```
paths: [
    "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]
]
```

In tsconfig so that app and library both use the same installed angular package.

Comment: This did not solve problem in my case.
I tried both paths: [
    {"@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]}
] and paths: {
    "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"]
}  in tsconfig of my app and not the library which i am installing