# How to use angular library locally with hot reload? [Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')]

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have two angular projects locally, the first one is for the custom library (createApplication=false) and the second one is test-app;

Now I want to use custom library's components inside test-app, with hot reload;

What I am doing is:

1. Run `npm run build --watch` inside library
2. Run `npm install ../library/dist/test-library` inside test-app

Everything is fine except one run time error inside console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')`

I am using this article as a guide: [link](https://dev.to/patelvimal/how-to-use-angular-library-locally-with-hot-module-reload-2m35)

Comment: Facing the same issue. If you remember, can you reply how did you resolve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You have only one last step to handle : config in angular.json.
Follow this article and you should be fine :

https://medium.com/@maravondra/angular-component-in-locale-usage-8536d91fc844

```json
"preserveSymlinks": true
```

Answer (score 0):

bit late to the party but I got this same issue on angular 16 today for **firstCreatePass** and **bindingStartIndex** without any updates - 117 tests failed for no reason! and "preserveSymlinks": true was already in the angular.json file - what I did was remove node_modules etc. and reinstalled libraries - cmds I used are as follows: hopefully is helps somebody in the future.

> rm -rf node_modules

> rm package-lock.json

> npm cache verify

> npm i