# Angular Library with PrimeNg throwing Error ('firstCreatePass')

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, pnpm-workspace

For the current project I am working on integrating an Angular application with a custom UI (Angular library), that is based on PrimeNg.

I am utilizing PrimeNg as usual like this:

```
// mac-login.html
<p-panel header="Login">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="p-field">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input pInputText [(ngModel)]="username" id="username" name="username" required />
    </div>
    <div class="p-field">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <p-password [(ngModel)]="password" id="password" name="password" required />
    </div>
    <div class="p-field">
      <p-button type="submit" label="Login"></p-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</p-panel>
```

And here:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, NgModule, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/panel';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/password';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'mac-login',
  templateUrl: './mac-login.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mac-login.scss']
})
export class macLogin {
  @Input() username: string = '';
  @Input() password: string = '';

  @Output() submitForm: EventEmitter<{ username: string; password: string }> = new EventEmitter();

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.username && this.password) {
      this.submitForm.emit({ username: this.username, password: this.password });
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    PanelModule,
    InputTextModule,
    PasswordModule,
    ButtonModule
  ],
  exports: [ macLogin ],
  declarations: [ macLogin ]
})
export class macLoginModule {}
```

When I am trying to use the component within my main app like this:

```
<mac-login
    [username]="user.email"
    [password]="user.password"
    (submitForm)="signIn()"
  ></mac-login>
```

And here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { IUser, AuthService } from '../../services/auth/cognito.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.page.scss'],
})
export class SignInPage {

  loading: boolean;
  user: IUser;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.user = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    } as IUser;
  }

  public signIn(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.signIn(this.user)
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    }).catch(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

}
```

I get the following error message:

```
main.ts:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')
    at providersResolver (core.mjs:22359:15)
    at definition.providersResolver (core.mjs:22620:24)
    at initializeDirectives (core.mjs:11935:17)
    at resolveDirectives (core.mjs:11909:13)
    at elementStartFirstCreatePass (core.mjs:15677:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:15713:9)
    at macLogin_Template (mac-login.html:1:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11409:17)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12608:13)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:12555:5)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:27127:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:27127:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:27437:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:171:47)
```

I have correctly imported the library in app.module.ts

The whole ui-libary is propagated through pnpm workspaces.

Is there any way to solve this? THanks in advance.

Comment: You may find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656063/angular-typeerror-cannot-read-property-firstcreatepass-of-null

Comment: Thanks @AbhinavKumar, but unfortunately, there is not a correct answer inside that answer block.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have been reading in forums and through posts countless hours, just to finally find the answer, that has not been so obvious.

When working with **pnpm workspaces** with **multiple Angular projects**, there is an issue with package management, where Angular Ivy is provided in multiple instances, so that e.g. the library's Ivy does not exactly match the app's Ivy (from node_modules) - causing an Ivy madness within the app.

In order to avoid this, we need to make sure, that the app and the connected library are **using @angular from node_modules only**!

And it is really easy to set up. Add the following to your app's tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ...,
  compilerOptions: {
    ...,
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And that's it. Working like a charm in Angular 16.2.0.